# How to detect whether a struct's member is a bit-field at compile time in C++?

Tags: c++, sfinae, type-traits, bit-fields

Given a struct S:

```
struct S {
  bool a : 1;
  bool b : 1;
};
```

How to determine that `S::a` and `S::b` are bit-fields at compile time?

I was trying to come up a macro like `IsBitField(S, a)` but had hard time to apply SFINAE with `offsetof()` or `addressof()` (which are known to be *invalid* operations per bit-fields).

Comment: I think those are UB and not SFINAE.

Comment: My guess would be that since [`<type_traits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) doesn't have any tools mentioning bit fields, and since [cppreference doesn't mention any SFINAE errors caused by bit fields](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae), this probably isn't possible using templates. There might be some compiler built-ins that could help, but those wouldn't be portable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, for a SFINAE solution, the ellipsis overload trick (with expression SFINAE) still works, we just need to find a construct that is ill-formed when applied to a bitfield while well-formed when applied on a normal member.

For example, you cannot form a pointer-to-member if the member is a bitfield.

So we could write:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct is_bit_field_t {
    template <typename U>
    static constexpr bool helper(...) {
        return true;
    }
    template <typename U>
    static constexpr bool helper(decltype(&U::a) arg) {
        return false;
    }
    static constexpr bool value = helper<T>(nullptr); 
};
```

This will test whether the public member `a` of `U` is of bitfield type. Explanation:

- If `T::a` is a bitfield, then the expression `decltype(&U::a)` would be ill-formed, which would then SFINAE out the second overload.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/TTn8YPKW3

---

With C++20, this could be done with concepts, utilizing the fact that you cannot take the address of a bitfield.

The core implementation would just look like:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept A_IsBitField = !requires (T t) {
     { &t.a };
};
```

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/W3jbosY93

If you hate to define a standalone concept, you could just use the `requires` expression instead (with the SFINAE method you have no choice but to create that struct)

---

Of course, the above only works for the member named `a`. If you would like to use it with other members, then you need to rewrite the SFINAE trait or the concept, replacing `a` with whatever member you want. You could write a macro to help you generate those constructs if you need a lot of them.

Comment: Shouldn't that concept be named `A_IsNotBitField`?

Comment: @RayHamel Fixed, though I guess it's easier just to add a `!` before the requires...

Comment: is it a common thing that people use macro factories to create many functions? Whenever I encounter this as the last solution, I try to resist using it as it's such an anti-generic solution. is it viable?